# Epson TM-T88VI Receipt Printer with ChromeOS

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, printing, printer, google-chrome-os

I am aware this is a niche topic but I will try to explain this as clearly and concisely as possible.  I manage multiple Chromebooks and on some of these devices they will be processing transactions through a web-based point of sale system called Club Automation.  I also have an Epson TM-T88VI receipt printer that is network capable.  I would like for there to be a way to print wirelessly (ideally) to these printers from the ChromeOS devices.  Right now we are running Windows computers and it works great using spooling.  I have tried running an instance of Linux and using the developer tools to install CUPS and had no luck.  I would not be opposed to setting up a print server if that would be an easier option.  I just have had no luck and would really appreciate any help I can get.  Thank you so much!

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... `I had no luck` is not a useful description of a problem ... why did CUPS attempt fail?

Comment: Are your devices 'managed' within Google admin console? If so here are the steps: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7276100#zippy=%2Cadd-a-printer

Comment: Although ChromeOS isn't technically supported, you might be able to make something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipp-cups-printing-for-chr/lkhfeoafdgbaecajkdbioenncjopbpmk?hl=en-GB) work.  Have you tried anything like this?